# My progress bar does not hide even after the data has been retrieved from firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, progress-bar

MY PROBLEM - I am displaying some data intro recycler view which is being retrieved from firebase, it takes around 2sec after the activity opens so i m trying to show a progress bar ubtil the data is being retrieved, the prgressbar is shown when it is supposed to but it doesnot hide when the data is loaded

MY MainActivity.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".CircularAct">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter class

```
package com.sjsbhints.pdfmanager;

         import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
      import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

      public class CAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cmodel,CAdapter.myViewHolder> {

ProgressBar progressBar;

/**
 * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
 * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public CAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cmodel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Cmodel model) {


    holder.Cdate.setText(model.getCdate());
 holder.Cheading.setText(model.getCheading());
   holder.Cbody.setText(model.getCbody());


}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.circular_item,parent,false);

    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView Cdate,Cheading,Cbody,Ndate,Nheading,Nsheading,Nbody,Tdate,Tsubject,Ttopic,Ttdate;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

     Cdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cdate);
       Cheading = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cheading);
       Cbody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbody);
       progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    }
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    if (progressBar != null){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

}

After doing all the my Progressbar does not hide after the data is loaded it stays there

Comment: I think that this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) might help you understand how to display a ProgressBar while getting data from the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.

Comment: @Gr8BEAST where are you using ProgressBar? I haven't seen it on your project? Please add these code also where you are using `ProgressBar`.

Comment: @MDEV I m using the progress bar in the xml with the recycler view and in the adapter class in the ondatachange function the progress bar is support to hide but it does not .... I saw a lot of yt video but they all say what I did.. But mine didn't work.. Please help